# How to get current user's Pager number as part of MS Outlook Add-In using C#?

Tags: outlook, add-in

Currently I am developing an Add-In for MS Outlook 2010 using C# in VS2010. This will create an extra Menu in the ContextMenu when ever we click on the email id. On click of that menu it will display the corresponding user's pager no.

I've followed these instructions for [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172%28office.14%29.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_SampleAddin)

I can able to retrieve all user details like Address, First Name or Phone number etc. But I can't able to retrieve the Pager number.

See the code below for the same:

```cs
    public void OnGetEmpIdClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        try
        {
            Office.IMsoContactCard card = control.Context as Office.IMsoContactCard;

            if (card != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(GetEmpId(card), "Employee Id", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to access contact card");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private string GetEmpId(Office.IMsoContactCard card)
    {
        if (card.AddressType == Office.MsoContactCardAddressType.msoContactCardAddressTypeOutlook)
        {
            Outlook.Application host = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
            Outlook.AddressEntry ae = host.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(card.Address);

            if ((ae.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry || 
                ae.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry))
            {
                Outlook.ExchangeUser ex = ae.GetExchangeUser();
                return ex.BusinessTelephoneNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Valid address entry not found.");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            return card.Address;
        }
    }
```

But Pager number property is not available. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried:

```
Outlook.ExchangeUser ex = ae.GetExchangeUser();
return ex.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A21001F");
```

and it worked for me.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb446002.aspx for other Mail User Properties.